# Unable to add a core in Solr 3.6

Tags: apache, solr

I'm trying to add multiple cores in solr 3.6 but i'm unable to do it. I wrote the following in solr.xml file

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
         <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
    </cores>
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="./core1">
         <property name="dataDir" value="./core1/data" />
    </core> 
</solr>
```

core1 is the new core i want to create, I copied the config folder of the default core into core1, when I try to access localhost:8983/solr/core1/admin I get 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New core should be defined within the cores tag :-

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
         <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
         <core name="core1" instanceDir="./core1">
              <property name="dataDir" value="./core1/data" />
         </core> 
    </cores>
</solr>
```